# when combining features and then aggregating them featuretools returns some variables that don't make sense, how can this be avoided?

Tags: featuretools

I've got a dataset that contains invoices, with a unique identifier, and customers with a unique identifier. Each customer can have 1 or more invoices.

I set up the entity sets as follows:

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id="data")

es = es.add_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    dataframe_name="data",     
    index="rows",              
    make_index=True,           
    time_index="invoice_date", 
    logical_types={
"customer_id": Categorical,
"description": NaturalLanguage,
}
)

es.normalize_dataframe(
    base_dataframe_name="data",     
    new_dataframe_name="invoices",  
    index="invoice",               
    copy_columns=["customer_id"],
)

es.normalize_dataframe(
    base_dataframe_name="invoices",
    new_dataframe_name="customers",  
    index="customer_id",
)
```

So that customers is child of invoices which is child of the entire dataset.

Now, I want to combine the variables price and quantity at the entire dataframe level, to obtain price*quantity, which happens all good. But when aggregating, I see combinations of variables that don't make human sense (or maybe it is me who does not understand them).

I set up the dfs as follows:

```
date_primitives = ["month", "weekday"]
text_primitives = ["num_words"]
trans_primitives = date_primitives + text_primitives + ["multiply_numeric"]

agg_primitives = ["mean"]

feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,       
    target_dataframe_name="customers",     
    agg_primitives=agg_primitives,         
    trans_primitives=trans_primitives,        
    primitive_options={               
        ("multiply_numeric"): {
            'include_columns': {
                'data': ['price', 'quantity']
        }
    }
    },
    max_depth=3,
)
```

and the result of dfs contains the following features:

```
[<Feature: MEAN(data.price)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.quantity)>,
 <Feature: MONTH(first_invoices_time)>,
 <Feature: WEEKDAY(first_invoices_time)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.NUM_WORDS(description))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price * quantity)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price) * MEAN(data.quantity)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.NUM_WORDS(description)))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price * quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price) * MEAN(data.quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price * quantity) * MEAN(data.price)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price * quantity) * MEAN(data.quantity)>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price * quantity) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price * quantity) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.price) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.quantity) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(data.quantity) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity))>,
 <Feature: MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price)) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity))>]
```

From those, these feature MEAN(data.price * quantity)> makes sense to me, the variations of this feature MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price * quantity))> also make sense to me. But features like these ones MEAN(data.quantity) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price)), MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.price)) * MEAN(invoices.MEAN(data.quantity)), don't make sense to me.

I was wondering if they could be prevented from the output? I tried reducing the depth, but that would prevent the text primitive from executing. So not sure what else I can try?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

You can use the `drop_contains` argument for `dfs`. It drops features that contain the specified string.

A sample call to `dfs` would be:

```py
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,       
    target_dataframe_name="customers",     
    agg_primitives=agg_primitives,         
    trans_primitives=trans_primitives,        
    primitive_options={               
        ("multiply_numeric"): {
            'include_columns': {
                'data': ['Price', 'Quantity']
        }
    }   
    },
    drop_contains=[") * MEAN("], 
    max_depth=3,
)
```